# How do I access external hosts from within my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a container with a specialized application that needs to connect to hosts, via DNS lookup, outside of the Kubernetes cluster. When I run the container standalone in Docker, things work fine.

When I run the container using Kubernetes though, I'm getting "host not found" errors. If I run bash inside the container, and do a "ping myhost.mydomain.com
", it fail to resolve myhost.mydomain.com.

Reading through the Kubernetes pages, it appears all I need to do is this add this service:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myhost
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: myhost.mydomain.com`

But, this doesn't seem to work; the container still can't ping myhost or myhost.mydomain.com. Is there something else I need to add? Is there some way to have a "fallback" DNS so that any external hostname can be resolved? It doesn't seem like this should be this difficult...

Thanks,
John

Comment: is myhost.mydomain.com a publicly resolvable subdomain ? Normaly kubedns should have no issues resolving public domain names at all, so maybe this is some internal dns ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. From the command line of the cluster node (i.e. not within a container), the DNS resolution works fine.

Comment: yes, but your node dns might ie. be using an internal dns server that provides resolution to domains that are not publicly resolvable. Does something like `host myhost.mydomain.com 8.8.8.8` return a correct IP for the service ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` to the spec.

Comment: That was a big step forward... I also had to add ```hostNetwork: true```. Now, hostnames that are stored in the host server's ```/etc/hosts``` file resolve without a problem, but it still won't do the normal DNS lookup. I'd rather not depend on the ```/etc/hosts``` file. Is there some way to make it do a DNS lookup for any hostname as needed, if it's not within the cluster?